# Start a SeleniumWebDriver Instance when Google Chrome has been already opened

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I want to be able to run an automation that uses SeleniumWebDriver with Node.js.

 The thing is I can't start the automation if Google Chrome is already opened and being used by the user.

For the moment I solved this by closing all Chrome instances before starting the automation, 
 but it doesn't seem a good solution to me.

The following is the configuration code I use to setup selenium webdriver:

```js
async function setupSelenium(headless) {
    const userDataDir =
        "/Users/matteobaldassarre/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/";

    const options = new Options()
        .addArguments(`--user-data-dir=${userDataDir}`)
        .addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
        .addArguments("--start-maximized");

    if (headless) options.addArguments("--headless=new")

    let driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser("chrome")
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .build();

    await driver
        .manage()
        .setTimeouts({ implicit: 10000 });

    return driver;
}
```

Keep in mind that I want to run Chrome with the Default profile (the one that the user is probably using when the other chrome instance is open).

I tried using the --remote-debugging-port argument because it seems that's the only way to start two instances with the same profile, but when I run the automation I get this error:

```
session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. 
(chrome not reachable) 
(The process started from chrome location /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Comment: don't think you can do that.   You can, however, just let Selenium create a temporary profile for each session.  (just don't set any options... it'll create a temporary profile for each session... and choose an available port)  You could create a new profile (manually, in the browser) for each session you want and then set the driver to use one of those for each.

Comment: @browsermator but by creating a temporary profile wouldn't I loose all session data of the default profile? the thing is that I am trying to use the default because keeps the session to the website I need to do the automation later on (I cannot automate the login process since there's a QR Code to scan and some manual steps to do on the phone, so I excluded this at the beginning)

Comment: either way you'll be losing the session stuff, since each time you launch you will have a new session.  You can create a profile in Chrome manually that has whatever sort of "remember me" type values already stored, (login manually using that profile) and use that.  I believe you can only use one profile at a time.

Answer (score 0):

To open a new window you can use the newWindow() method. Here's how you can do it:

```
// Opens a new window and switches to new window
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.WINDOW);
```

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# Set up WebDriver options
options = Options() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome Beta\\User Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default")

# Use webdriver_manager to automatically install the correct ChromeDriver
driver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Set up the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://www.vk.com")

driver.switch_to.new_window('window')
driver.get("https://www.x.com")

driver.switch_to.new_window('window')
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, but the problem is not about opening a new window, the Chrome window opens but then stops working because there was an instance of Google Chrome already opened.